# Debian 7 - Startx fails to start system

Tags: xorg, console, boot-loader, x-server, startx

When I boot into the second primary boot loader, I get to the text based console to boot when I type 'startx'. The screen loads, and goes black for 10 seconds. Then when it loads a white screen appears with a computer monitor an sad face on it. Under it, it says

```
"Oh no! Something has gone wrong"
A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again
```

When I click the logout button in the console it reports the errors as follows:

```
X.Org X Server 1.12.4
Release Date: 2012-08-27
X Protocol Version 11, revision 0
build operating system: Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
....
The XKEYBOARD Keypmap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> warning:  compat map for group 2 redefined
> using new definition
> warning:  compat map for group 3 redefined
> using new definition
> warning:  compat map for group 4 redefined
> using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
xinit: connection to X server lost

Waiting for X server to shut down server terminated successfully (0). closing the file
```

Does anyone know how I can successfully boot into my operating system with startx and avoid getting these errors?

Comment: What video hardware do you have? Did you try with another desktop environment except Gnome?

Comment: I am using AMD Radeon graphics, and no I didn't try another DE, how do I? I ran into an earlier problem, this was supposed to be a work around, but it isn't working either! I can't lose my projects on the hard drive. It's due friday, and I have to get it done, its on there...

Comment: I suggest you install a display manager (like kdm, gdm, slim...), install another DE (KDE or XFCE for example) then, from the DM's menu you can choose the DE to use so that you can finish your projects. Debian's documentation will help you, I'd start with the wiki.

Comment: This is no solution, but if you're really stuck, you could boot with some distro LiveCD/DVD and at least access the files on the drive and back them up for use on another machine.